# Codehaus.org shut down today. Is there a list somewhere that says where its projects have moved to?

Tags: castor

Or, does anyone happen to know where Castor in particular has gone, if it's still going to live somewhere?  Its source is here but without any helpful additional info: https://github.com/codehaus/castor

Codehaus' blog post about their history and the shutdown, for reference:
http://www.codehaus.org/about/history.html

Edit: 
The comments here https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9161562 imply that when they announced the shutdown, they said that project SVN:

> Will all be migrated to Github - SVN repos will be migrated to Git and transferred into the "codehaus" Github account. This is a readonly account. Inactive projects may be migrated ahead of the shutdown.

And thanks NealC for pointing to this tweet that indicates that nexus.codehaus.org will continue to be available after the shutdown. 
https://twitter.com/codehaus/status/594042932107186176

**TL;DR: Source is now on github under the codehaus account, and the maven repo is still available.**

Comment: Even though this question is low quality, here is a link to a tweet that might answer some questions. https://twitter.com/codehaus/status/594042932107186176

Comment: Thanks Neal, that's very helpful.  If you're inclined to do so I'd love to receive feedback about what makes it a low quality question - looking at the help center article about asking I didn't think I was violating any standards.  (Though admittedly it's an awfully boring question.)

Comment: Well, stackoverflow is made for questions more towards actual programming. Although codehaus is programming tool/platform/etc.

Comment: Maven deps are so near to programming, if they don't work you cannot code. Programming environment questions are fine, also. There is a debate on it, but they're ok still.

Comment: Codehous' blog post about their history, archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20160304052739/http://www.codehaus.org/history/